# Help! I need something better than MS word for my UX spec docs

Tags: guidelines, documentation, resources, style-guide

My team and I have been using MS word to deliver UX specs to our developers.  Our documents include a section for final visuals, content, wireframes, interaction notes, and business analysis flows.  In short, these MS word documents are NOT short and are impossible to navigate as they are static linear documents. I would not wish these documents on anyone.

What my team needs (no compromises):

- A design spec that contains IX, BA, Visuals, Content, & attached files
- Simultaneous editing
- Version control
- A non-linear format with navigation
- PC & Mac supported

What won't work: Axure, RTF docs & PDFs

What I heard others use: Zurb tools, Jira, a Wiki

**What solution would you strongly recommend?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is seeking suggestions on software, rather than a specific usability concept of concern. Any answers given would be purely opinion-based and would quickly be obsolete as the market changes. Please visit the [help center](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help) for information on what types of questions fit best within the StackExchange network.

Comment: I use a combination of HTML (with notes in revealed divs); annotated photoshop documents; visio docs for flows; excel and word for dB related information. This is a long and involved topic. It seems like the community is not fond of dealing with questions like this - though it is something that most of us struggle with.

Comment: I would love to see this question live on. It's a problem we all face. Here's what I'm doing: A high-level doc in Google Slides that presents the problems and goals, possibly some rough proposals, and links to everything else. The nice part about a central link list is that your other docs can vary by the project's needs. Most often, the list includes a requirements doc (either in Google Docs or HTML); Axure wires; storyboard in a separate Slides doc; and some visual mock-ups in a Drive folder.

Comment: I understand whatever the community chooses.  I do feel this pertains to the usability of the documents we procure, but perhaps that's a stretch.

Comment: @Andrew - the [chat section](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/389/ux-chat) could be a resource that might help you on a question like this. The issue with the language of the question, as is, is that any answers are highly subjective and a specific to one project or one style of work style. There is no "right answer" to this type of question -- StackExchange is a Q&A site, where questions should have right answers. The chat section is an open discussion forum where answers are open to the whimzy of the author.

Answer (score 0):

I've been surprised with how versatile OneNote can be in storing spec info, files, long form text, images, etc.

You can have todo's, stars, questions, etc.

It's fully searchable, you can create links, has paging/grouping capabilities and supports multiple users editing at the same time (though I don't think you can see realtime changes), with some basic change tracking.

It's also available on a Mac.

What I did at a previous job was have a shared OneNote that had sections broken down by feature/user story. Within each section then we had spec, mockups, functional and technical documentation. It was simple, with little setup, and had a low barrier to entry.